# Как обойти регистр букв для имени папки?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Подскажите как прописать путь к папке одной строкой, чтобы не использовать две строки ради определения заглавной буквы и маленькой. В разных версиях Windows они различаются.

```
args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
var filePath = args[1];
var fileFolderDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);
var systemFolderLS = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%SystemRoot%\\System32");
var systemFolderLs = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%SystemRoot%\\system32");
if ((fileFolderDir == systemFolderLs) || (fileFolderDir == systemFolderLS))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Проверка", "Сообщение")
}
```

Comment: [Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System));](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Спасибо за такой вариант.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно сравнивать без учета регистра

```
var fileFolderDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);
var systemFolderLS = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%SystemRoot%\\System32");
if (fileFolderDir.Equals(systemFolderLS, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Проверка", "Сообщение")
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно. Для папок указанных вручную.